# Open big CSV file, remove a line and then save a copy

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I want to open a big CSV file (~2GB) in Python with the delimiter as "; " (semicolon and space), search for a specific word and if it appears in a line to remove the whole line. Although I can do the process described above, when I try to save the .CSV file, the delimiter changes and I cannot set a "customized" delimiter as "; ". Changing the delimiter is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bash shell to do that (if loading 2GB file is an issue).

The following expression uses regex`\\bYOUR_WORD\nn` (replace YOUR_WORD with your specific word) and will create a new file without that condition.

Also, this would not consume a lot of RAM. This may take some time depending on the number of lines.

```
while read line; do [[ $line =~ \\bYOUR_WORD\\b ]] || echo $line; done <  file.csv > newfile.csv
```